# Network Share sometimes missing some folders

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-sharing

I have a Public network share that all computers on the campus can access.  One of these computers occasionally 'loses' about 8 out of 10 of the folders in this mapped drive.

I have toggled client side caching both ways, removed and remapped the drive, refreshed DNS, IP, and group policy with no success.  A restart fixed the problem but I would like to know what is happening.

We did push updates the day before so I'm wondering if that 'locked' something.

**Edit** This is a share on a Win Server 2012 R2 standard.

Comment: Windows 7 has a sharing limit of 20 simultaneous connections this could be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders that remained, at some point, had been added to Offline Files in Sync Center.  Sync Center didn't play nice and let me remove those folders so disabling Offline Files entirely was the only solution.